# Assign value to field/Instance variable in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Please consider below scenario.

```
Class Abc{
  private String test;

  public void assign(String abc) {
    abc="xyz"; // press ctrl+Alt+V - 2 times.
    this.test = "xyz" // is there any shortcut to assign value to field/instance variable.?
    
    }
  }
```

We can assign values to existing local variables by pressing ctrl+alt+v - 2 times.
is there any shortcut that assign values to class fields/instance variables in a method in Intellij Idea? ex- this.test = "xyz".

I raised youtrack request to find solution but no response.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-349134/Assign-value-to-field-Instance-Variable

**Edit**-

Tried with Ctrl+Alt+F - It creates new field but dont perform assignment to existing field.
[image]

Comment: If you look at the menu "Refactor" -> "Extract/Introduce" you can find entries for "Variable" (Ctrl-Alt-V) and "Field" (Ctrl-Alt-F). Do you search for that "Field" shortcut?

Comment: @ThomasKläger, Ctrl-Alt-F creates a new field and assign it. it dont links to existing Fields. I am wondering why such important feature is missing in Intellij. I have added screenshot of testing.

Comment: Hi Ajay. I updated https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-349134 with your comments. Our Java developers will take a look at the issue. In the meantime, you can use the workaround provided in this comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-349134#focus=Comments-27-9567769.0-0

Answer (score 1):

When introducing a field you probably want to select the 'Initialize' in option for initialization as 'field declaration'

[image]